# Windows (or cross-platform) app to copy strings from any window, especially error messages

Tags: windows, windows-7, software-testing, accessibility, copy-paste

I'm seeking recommendations for gratis software that will run on Windows that can copy strings from any window, especially from error message windows / message boxes.

In particular, the app must be able to copy strings from windows in which normal copy/paste functionality is not present (such as most error message windows... ugh).

Cross-platform recommendations are most welcome, but at the least, the app must run on Windows 7.

Historically, I've used [NirSoft's SysExporter](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html), but unlike all the other wonderful NirSoft apps, I don't find this particular app to work in many situations.

Portable apps (no installer, and no writing to the Windows registry) are strongly preferred, but that is not a hard requirement.

The app must not include any forced telemetry or other required forms of internet access.

Answer (score 1):

GetWindowsText
https://softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/GetWindowText

But you can copy text from standard error windows simply by press CTRL+C

Answer (score 1):

The Windows scripting language AutoIt comes with a tool named [AutoIt Window Information Tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) that allows to extract a lot of details from every Window, dialog and even control in a dialog/window.

It allows to select a target window easily using drag & drop of the **Finder Tool**.

The extracted text is visible in the tab **Visible text**.

The tool is included in the AutoIt download package: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

As you only want the Window Information tool you can download the "AutoIt– Self Extracting Archive" version.
Download it, open it using an archiver like 7-Zip and extract `Au3Info_x64.exe`. This EXE file works standalone as it is and does not need anything else from the archive.

Comment: Wow. That looks incredible.  Thank you.  I'm not currently using AutoIt, so I'll see if I can just extract that tool and use it by itself.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket On the download page is an "AutoIt– Self Extracting Archive" version, that should be best. Download it, open it using an archiver like 7-Zip and extract `Au3Info_x64.exe`. The EXE file works out of the box and does not need anything from the AutoIt installation.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  That's exactly what I was going to try, so I sincerely appreciate knowing in advance that it should work.  As a quick aside, I see AutoIt hasn't had any recent updates.  Do you know if the project is still active and alive?  I remember using it years ago, and it was a pleasure to use... very powerful too.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I only use AutoIt occasionally, so I have not noticed that there were any new releases.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your info, in most MessageBoxes you actually *can* copy the content, just by pressing `<ctrl><c>`. This works if the system dialogs where used.

Comment: Thanks. I need to see if this works for the message boxes I receive.  Most of the software I use is cross-platform, so often the message boxes are not native for the OS.  Because the text isn't selectable. I admit that I'm not sure if I've simply tried just pressing `ctrl+c`; ~99% of the time you need to select text before copying it! :)  I'll definitely try your tip in the future.  Thank you.